# Analyze a wireless network that constantly drops/has speed issues

Tags: internet, wireless-networking, connection

I'm curious what the best tools are to use for analyzing problems with a WiFi network.

Here's the scenario:

I have a WiFi router (Belkin N+) that's setup in AP mode.  I have three RT-N13U's that I've purchased to use as 'repeaters', but I've had so many problems when more than one of them is running (bad routes) that I've only got one active.

Sometimes certain boxes on my network can't talk to others, and drops are quite frequent and quite aggravating.

I'm running Mac, Windows, and Linux (Gentoo) boxes on this network, so any software, or steps I should take that work for any of those boxes should be sufficient.

Apologies if this is answered somewhere else - I'll close it as a dupe if so.

Comment: Have you tried to either disable n or go only n? Mixed mode networks have been known to have horrible connectivity issues.

Comment: I'm also wondering this. If you can, give a shot on the following link, and let us know! :) http://superuser.com/questions/125615/finding-wireless-interference

Answer (score 0):

NetSpot is a free, simple and accessible wireless survey tool for Mac users, which allows collecting, visualizing and analyzing Wi-Fi data using any MacBook.
It can visualize your wireless network by building a visual Wi-Fi map. It will let you see dead zones without coverage and place hotspots correctly. Using the visualized map of collected wireless data you will also see channels' load and will be able to decide how to optimize your Wi-Fi site better.

If you need free version visit [NetSpot website](http://netspotapp.com/)

Comment: So, how should OP use this tool to diagnose his network problems?