# Finding wireless interference

Tags: wireless-networking, interference

I want to find out if wireless interference is causing any problems with my wireless networks. I remember seeing a piece of software that let you see what networks where in range and where they fell in the spectrum, aswell as any other sources.

Anyone know a way/a piece of software that can do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[inSSIDer](http://www.metageek.net/) by Metageek was recommended in a recent [PC Pro article](http://www.pcpro.co.uk/realworld/356446/banish-your-wi-fi-woes) and the hardware device Wi-Spy looks good for more advanced troubleshooting.

Comment: If you're dealing with 2.4GHz, get the Wi-Spy. There are plenty of non-802.11 interferers in 2.4, thus invisible to Wi-Fi network scanners like InSSIDer.

Comment: @Spiff and Cowen: would you guys know of any similar software for mac?

Comment: @Cawas, you could ask that as a real Question and we could all get reputation points for it! :-)  The `airport` command-line tool is built-in to Mac OS X, and it has a `-s` option to scan. "/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Resources/airport -s". GUI tools include iStumbler, KisMAC, and several Dashboard and Yahoo ! (Konfabulator) widgets.

Comment: @Cawas, did you see http://www.metageek.net/docs/wireless-networking-tools covering Kismet and KisMAC?

Comment: @Spiff ok, all of you are welcome to answer it then: http://superuser.com/questions/126554/finding-wireless-interference-on-mac ;)