# Finding wireless interference, on Mac

Tags: macos, mac, wireless-networking, interference

Based on [another similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/125615/finding-wireless-interference), what are good software and hardware options on the Apple for finding what could be causing interference problems with the wireless network?

Comment: -2 on this question... You just can't win can you? :-(

Comment: lol @Josh. and not even 1 clarification on why!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at AirRadar

or for a little more serious with errant signal noise....

http://www.metageek.net/products/wi-spy-24i   [PC and Mac Compatible]

Cheers